# Retain Substate when reentering a State in Stateless?

Tags: c#, state-machine, stateless-state-machine

I have a state machine as shown below. I have implemented this in C# using [Stateless](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless).

The `On` state can reenter itself in case of the `RequestStatus` trigger. When this happens, the statemachine can be in any of the following states: `On`, `On > Standby` or `On > Operational`. Now, for this trigger, the current state should remain as it is and just the status should be returned i.e., execute `ReturnStatus()`.

Executing functions depending on the trigger can be done using the `OnEntryFrom(Trigger, Action)` method. But the problem is, if I set `OnEntryFrom` of `On` state, every time the trigger is triggered, if the either of the substates are active, they are first exited, then the `On` state is exited and then the `OnEntry` of `On` state occurs.

Now what I want is, regardless of which of the 3 states the statemachine is active in, for the `RequestStatus` trigger, just execute the `ReturnStatus()` method.

One way I could do this is set `OnEntryFrom(PowerOn, () => Initialize())` and `OnEntryFrom(RequestStatus, () => ReturnStatus())`. Do the same for the substates by adding new triggers `StandbyRequestStatus` and `OperationalRequestStatus` and trigger them according to which one was previously active. Which I think is tedious, especially if the number of substates grows.

The other way is to retain the substate and handle it just once. But I can't find a way to do this in Stateless.

Is it achievable using Stateless? Has anyone done this before?

[image: Stateless Statemachine Used]